# Do modern Nintendo DS games still work on the original DS?

Tags: backwards-compatibility, nintendo-ds

I'm attracted by the type of games you get on the Nintendo DS. I'm not looking to spend a lot of money, so would be happy to buy a pre-owned original DS, but will it still play *modern* DS games?

Obviously, I wouldn't be buying games that explicitly require DSi hardware features, but what level of support does the original generally get from new games? If it makes any difference, the kind of thing I'm interested in is [Professor Layton](http://www.nintendo.com/games/game-guide#filter/ds%7C-%7C-%7C-%7Cprofessor%20layton%7Cdescend%7CreleaseDate%7C-%7C-%7C-%7C-%7C-%7C-), and other adventure, mystery, and/or roleplaying games.

Comment: Excellent choice of game!! I would also highly recommend the [Phoenix Wright series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phoenix_Wright:_Ace_Attorney) and [999](http://www.destructoid.com/review-nine-hours-nine-persons-nine-doors-187838.phtml) if you can find them.

Comment: *Does this still hold true?* The original DS is now over 16 years old, and I have noticed that Nintendo still has games in their software library that are marked for the Nintendo DS. So, if I wanted to get [The Mysterious Case of Dr. Jekyll & Mr. Hyde](http://www.nintendo.com/games/detail/KV6jhQaZFB5qtfuAvPx6qGJAs-jIpd7l), which as of the date of this comment is the most recent game out there, would it work on a DS or DS Lite?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, all DS games out now are compatible with the original DS. Professor Layton will play just fine.

I don't know if any DSi only games are actually out, but if any get released, it will be stated on the packaging that the game only works on the DSi. I do know, however, that with the release of the 3DS there will be 3DS only games.

Comment: I don't know if there are any DSi-only games out either, but I do know that the packages will say DSi and look different (all white) than normal DS packages.  Also keep in mind that 3DS is coming out soon... a 3D gaming platform that doesn't require special glasses!

Comment: There is at least one DSi-only game, an RPG based on taking pictures. This can't be played on a normal DS or DS Lite due to the lack of a camera.

Comment: Just thought that I'd clarify that all 3DS games will be 3DS-only, and not backwards compatible. Just like PS3 games don't play on a PS2.

Comment: Ullalloo, You are wrong, PS3 60/80GB FAT = PS2 and PS3 games

Comment: @BaileyRowland, `@Ullallulloo isn't wrong. You can't play PS3 games on a PS2.

Comment: @BaileyRowland I'm not sure how the Playstation series work, but I do know that with most consoles, the later ones may have backwards-compatibility (both games and accessories), but earlier ones usually don't have forward-compatibility (i.e. Wii U games will not work in the original Wii). One exception is with dual-compatible Game Paks that work in Game Boy (both the original and Pocket versions) and Game Boy Color.